Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’: object ‘recvData’ is not exported by 'namespace:parallel'
I upoladed RStudio recently. I tried to then run a code that was working up until last week that requires the package "caret" and every time I try to load it, I get the error message
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’:
object ‘recvData’ is not exported by 'namespace:parallel'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘caret’ was built under R version 4.3.3
I tried to uninstall it and re-install it, to manually update the package launching RStudio as an admin, but it keeps telling me the same error and I can't find any information about it

The RStudio IDE wouldn't have any impact on this. What version of R do you have? What happens when you run install.packages("caret")?

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)"
whenever I try to install it, it tells me that
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
Restarting R session...
and then it proceeds to restart the session and it says that it was succesfully installed

Update your version of R to the latest version (4.4.1).

I did. It did nothing

When you open Rstudio what version of R is indicated?

R.version, row version.string to get your R version

I had the same error message a while ago and also could not find a work around. I tried deleting and reinstalling caret and all its dependencies, which might work for you if you are working in a base environment for which you have admin rights.
I was working with an external server and this occurred. For me the solution was to create a conda environment with the newest R-version and then installing everything anew in the environment.
